# Access div content from url

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a side menu where the link of each content are based on a hide and show div process. But when i use the back button the content of the next div that was viewed does not appear. How can i achieve this? I have read on jquery pushstate but i am still confuse. Please help.

An insight of my codes up to now:

```js
< script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" > < /script>
$(function() {
    var curPage="";
    $("#toggle a").click(function() {
        if (curPage.length) { 
            $("#"+curPage).hide();
        }
        curPage=$(this).data("page");
        $("#"+curPage).show();
    });
});
```

```css
.content {

  display: none;

}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div id="canvas">

    <div id="nav">
      <ul id="toggle">

        <li><a href="/home" data-page="page1">HOME</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#us" data-page="page2">ABOUT US</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#end" data-page="page3">PORTFOLIO</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <a href="#" class="toggle-nav" id="bars"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>


    <div id="main">
      <div id="page1" class="content">TEST ONE</div>

      <div id="page2" class="content">TEST TWO</div>

      <div id="page3" class="content">TEST THREE</div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can use href as page id then the code will become much more easier.You can avoid all the extra codes.

Thus menu will look like

```
<li>
    <a href="#about-us">ABOUT US</a>
</li>
```

no need to use `data-page="page2"`

page div should modified with the href id of the menu. like

```
<div id="about-us" class="content">TEST ONE</div>
```

This the jquery function simple becomes

```
$(function() {
    $(window).on('hashchange', function(e){
        $("#main .content").hide();
        $(window.location.hash).show();
    });
   if(window.location.hash != ""){
      $(window).trigger('hashchange');
    }
});
```

Hope this should help... :)

```js
$(function() {    
    $(window).on('hashchange', function(e){
        $("#main .content").hide();
        $(window.location.hash).show();
    });
    if(window.location.hash != ""){
        $(window).trigger('hashchange');
    }
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

  <div id="canvas">

    <div id="nav">
      <ul id="toggle">

        <li><a href="/home" data-page="page1">HOME</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#about-us">ABOUT US</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#portfolio" data-page="page3">PORTFOLIO</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <a href="#" class="toggle-nav" id="bars"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>


    <div id="main">
      <div id="about-us" class="content">About us ................</div>

      <div id="portfolio" class="content">Portfolio.............</div>

      <div id="contact" class="content">Contact ...........</div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: That fail to display any div content

Comment: i forgot to add the id changes, please follow the new instructions

Comment: it works but when i copy the url in a new tab it is blank again and no about us content is displayed

Comment: Updated the code with url change triggering.So that when someone type url directly, this will trigger a hashchange event if there is hashtag .  `if(window.location.hash != ""){
        $(window).trigger('hashchange');
    }`

Comment: Hope this will solve all your problems.if so please mark it as answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101696/discussion-between-neha-and-aneesh-rs).

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is to set the hash of the location and add a `setInterval()` to keep track of changes in the value of that hash.

You need to change the links just a bit:

```
<li><a href="#page2">ABOUT US</a></li>
```

Clicking the link will do nothing but set the hash value of the URL.

And here's the javascript (yours is not needed anymore):

```
$(function() {
    window.setInterval(function() {
        if(document.location.hash !== '') {
            $('.content').hide();
            $(document.location.hash).show();
        }
    }, 50);
});
```

Every 50 milliseconds, the hash will be checked and if it's not empty the value will be used to show the corresponding element.

[Everything brought together in a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h8k4zxo5/)

Comment: Thank you that worked, could you just ensure me if a user bookmarks for example the About us content page. will he still be able to access it days after?

Comment: Bookmarking should work just fine. When the hash is present in the bookmark URL, the javascript will fetch it and show the corresponding element.